# php returning undefined property

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

In other of not be repetitive, I wrote that `getName` function to do the duty job for me: the classes querying the database would only send the SQL query:

```
  public function getVolumeServer($id)
    {
        $str = "SELECT *FROM site_volume_server WHERE site_id='$id'";
        return $this->getName($str);
    }

    public function getName($str)
    {
        $data = array();
        $query = $this->getQuery($str);

        if($query){
            foreach($query->result() as $row){
                array_push($data, $row->name);
            }
        }

        return $data;

    }
    public function getQuery($str){
    $data = array();
    $query = $this->db->query($str);

    if(!$query || $query->num_rows() == 0){
        return false;
    }
    return $query;
}
```

However, I'm getting the following error:

```
<p>Severity: Notice</p>
<p>Message:  Undefined property: stdClass::$name</p>
<p>Filename: models/sitematrix_model.php</p>
<p>Line Number: 129</p>
```

Line 129 is `$this->getName($str)`.

I did not have that before, when that portion of code was embedded in the function, but there are similar functions that only differ by the table being accessed.
Any Thoughts?
Thanks

Comment: are you sure you have a row called `name` in `site_volume_server` table

Comment: `mysql> describe site_volume_server;
+-------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field       | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| site_id     | int(10) unsigned | NO   |     | 0       |       |
| server_id   | int(10) unsigned | NO   |     | 0       |       |
| name        | varchar(20)      | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| description | varchar(100)     | YES  |     | NULL    |       |`

Comment: Have you tried running the query in phpMyAdmin (or similar)? Is there a valid id being passed?

Comment: yes, I have ... `$id` is the same for all the functions;

Comment: How about debug the content of the `$row`? Use `var_dump($row)` to see whats going on...

Answer (score 0):

I am having the same problem except I am trying to access the `$agenda->time_from` property from `__get()` which is a time column in agenda table which is retrieved from db properly (I checked the var_dump, ran the query manually in phpMyAdmin).

I do that because the default call `parent::_get()` won't return the value; it returns `NULL` instead.

I found a workaround for my problem. All you need to do is to access the value like :

```
$agenda->_object['time_from']
```

I guess this is not quite the right solution, but working one.

Comment: yeah now I know thats not a solution, please somebody what now ? :(

Comment: You might be better off posting this as a new question with a link to this original one as additional reference and state off the bat that this has no answers.